# Recommendation Letter

Tags: new-job, manager, employees, employer

I got a new job as an engineer. My previous job was not engineering related. Anyhow, my previous boss wrote me a recommendation letter due to my outstanding performance. Do you recommend I send this recommendation letter to my new manager so he gets to know more about how I value a job or a task at hand regradless if it's engineering or not? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No.

I don't think you can gain much by doing so. You already got the job, promises and agreements already have been made, now it's time to deliver.

I would however recommend to attach it to your resume/CV on application to next job even if it's not engineer-related. Good recommendation letter is not something everybody has, and there is a time and place to submit it.

Congratulations on your job!

Comment: I see, I thought about submitting the recommendation letter to my new manager so he knows that I am trustworthy and gives him and me a relief of having to prove myself. Also, I thought that this would set the bar that I am open for challenging tasks and show that I am somebody that could be relied on. These traits were not really emphasized during my interview

Comment: Or it may be the other way around - submitting the letter after getting in may put you in position that you now have more to prove, because you "promise" more things. Smart manager will acknowledge the recommendation, but verify it nevertheless.

Comment: Whether it's a good idea to attach recommendation letters to an application seems like a question all on it's own: [Sending references and transcripts along with resume and cover letter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/13706)

Answer (score -1):

IMO, I would trot out the rec letter ONLY_IF it highlighted some kind of marketable skill set that you could then demonstrate is laterally transferable from the industry that previously employed you to the current and ONLY_IF that particular skill set was what the new job was seeking.  e.g. Engineers aren't exactly known for their effervescing, outgoing personalities, generally speaking, but if you were seeking a position as an engineer, and that position required client-facing skills, you will then want to mention how you developed a penchant for verbal tact and diplomacy skills with clients.  And lookee here, Mr./Ms. Interviewer, I even have proof of concept right here from Mr. Former Employer attesting to it.